# how can i find particular li from posted text

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created one script to find the correct answer and incorrect answer on click event of li I am posting data and fetch response if response is correct_ans at that time only one class will add which is correct-answer and if answer is not correct that I want to add 2 class like which answer they clicked on that href I will add incorrect-answer and I will post correct answer like correct answer is 456 and they select 1234 then I have to show incorrect-answer on 1234 href and correct-answer on 456 href

I have added my code given below in that I have to try siblings but it is not working and shows error: Uncaught ReferenceError: sibling is not defined

```js
$(this).find("a").addClass("active");
var answer = $(this).find("p").html();
//console.log(ID);
$.post('functions.php', {
  answer: answer
}, function(data) {

  //console.log(data);
  if (data != 'correct_ans') {
    console.log(data);
    if ($(".active").siblings("ul").$('li[text="' + data + '"]').length > 0) {
      alert('F');
    } else {
      alert('no F');
    }
    $(".active").addClass("incorrect-answer");
  } else {
    console.log(data);
    $(".active").addClass("correct-answer");
  }
  //$(".answer-list").css("pointer-events","none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="answer-list" id="answer_list1">
  <li>
    <a tabindex="1" id="question1">
      <span class="letter-option">A.</span>
      <div>
        <p>123</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <a tabindex="2" id="question1">
      <span class="letter-option">B.</span>
      <div>
        <p>456</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a tabindex="3" id="question1">
      <span class="letter-option">C.</span>
      <div>
        <p>789</p>
      </div>
    </a>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a tabindex="4" id="question1">
      <span class="letter-option">D.</span>
      <div>
        <p>1234</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
</ul>
```

so can anybody help me in this.

Comment: Of course you get this error, what is _sibling_ and where do you define it? What's going on here: `sibling.text(data)` ?

Comment: I mean I have use $(".active").siblings( "ul" ).$('li[text="'+data+'"]').length > 0 this

Comment: And you still get `Uncaught ReferenceError: sibling is not defined`?

Comment: yes I have still received this error

Comment: Update your post with new code. I don't see any _sibling_ there if we replace `sibling.text(data).length > 0` with `$(".active").siblings( "ul" ).$('li[text="'+data+'"]').length > 0`

Comment: You have one `li` element that already has the class `active`, and you are adding it to one or more `a` elements as well. Neither of those have a `ul` element as _sibling_ anywhere.

Comment: You can't get this error now. And what do you want to select with $(".active").siblings( "ul" ).$('li[text="'+data+'"]')? It cant' work

Comment: in that case, how can I add correct-answer class in this

Comment: You could define variable for _li_ element before $.post `var element = $(this);` and use it in function below `element.find('a').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer

Use this

```html
$("a:contains("+data+")").addClass("correct-answer");
```